# Set negative minDistance on Trackball? (or, combining PointerLock and Trackball)

Tags: three.js, trackball, pointerlock

Perhaps that's no the way to approach it, but I'm looking for a sort of a combination of PointerLock and Trackball controls - I want to be able to move the dolly endlessly in and out with scrolling like PointerLock, but be able to drag around and pan around and move in all axis like Trackball.

I've tried searching for ways for days but just couldn't find a way...any easy way to do this?

Thanks!